# Copy files from one location to another: access not allowed error message

Tags: applescript

I'm making a script to replace a folder in the Containers folder in the home user's library. So far, the code below works fine. Nothing wrong with it. The issue is, because it *moves* the files rather than copy them, it can only be run once. However, if I try and change `move` to `copy`, I get the following error:

Can’t set filepath with replacing to «class ects» of «class cfol» ((path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:Folder1"). Access not allowed.

Can anyone tell me why this is and how to fix it?

```
set filepath to (get path to home folder) & "Library:Containers:Folder1" as string
tell application "Finder" to move entire contents of folder ((path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:Folder1") to filepath with replacing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot just replace `move` with `copy`, because Finder's AppleScript Dictionary says the following about the `copy` *command*:

> copy v : (NOT AVAILABLE YET) Copy the selected items to the clipboard (the Finder must be the front application)

**Use the `duplicate` *command* instead:**

> **duplicate** v : Duplicate one or more object(s)
>       **duplicate** specifier : the object(s) to duplicate
>       [**to** location specifier] : the new location for the object(s)
>       [**replacing** boolean] : Specifies whether or not to replace items in the destination that have the same name as items being duplicated
>       [**routing suppressed** boolean] : Specifies whether or not to autoroute items (default is false). Only applies when copying to the system folder.
>       [**exact copy** boolean] : Specifies whether or not to copy permissions/ownership as is
>       → specifier : to the duplicated object(s)

**Example:**

```
set filepath to (get path to home folder) & "Library:Containers:Folder1" as string
tell application "Finder" to duplicate entire contents of folder ((path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:Folder1") to filepath with replacing
```

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot.